# Some conditions on a finite non-abelian $2$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $2$-group,  $\nu(G)$ denotes the number of 
conjugacy classes of non-normal subgroups of $G$
and $G^{\prime}$ denotes the  derived subgroup of $G$. If $|G^{\prime}|=8$ and $\nu(G)=4$,
is it true that $G\cong Q_{32}$?($Q_{32}$ is the generalized quaternion group of order 32).

Remark: By a GAP code I could see that the answer is yes for such groups of small order in the GAP library.
To prove it I think that I must show that $G$ has a unique subgroup of order 2.
Because by a well-known result, if $G$ is a finite $p$-group and contains a unique subgroup of order $p$, then
it is cyclic or  generalized quaternion group.

Any comment and help will be greatly appreciated!